# Upvote downvote functionality in node js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am having trouble to find a good way to implement a upvote/downvote functionality with Pug(jade) on the frontend and express backend. My current setup looks like this. I loop over items in my mongo db to display rating items.

```
each val in post['listitem']
    div.listitem
       .rating_button
         .buttons
           button(class='up' aria-pressed="false") Upvote
           p#vote 0 //currently 0 later data from db
           button(class='down' ariapressed="false")Downvote
```

Then I have a client side ajax call to my api

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.up', function(){
        var up = $.post("/api/:id/upvote", {changeBy: 1}, function(dataBack){
            $("#vote").text(dataBack); 
        });
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.down', function(){
        var down = $.post("/api/:id/downvote", {changeBy: 1},
        function(dataBack){
            $("#vote").text(dataBack);
        });
      });
    });
```

Api looks like that - First the siteController

```
exports.upvote = async (req, res) => {
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
vote += parseFloat(req.body.changeBy);
res.write(JSON.stringify(vote));
res.end();
console.log(vote);}

exports.downvote = async (req, res) => {
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
vote -= parseFloat(req.body.changeBy);
res.write(JSON.stringify(vote));
res.end();
console.log(vote);}
```

Second my index.js

```
router.post('/api/:id/upvote', siteController.upvote);
router.post('/api/:id/downvote', siteController.downvote);
```

Everything is working as expected but with this setup the buttons in my loop are not working properly. Only the first button is increasing/decreasing the number by 1.

How do I solve the problem with the buttons in the loop? And any inspiration/ideas to improve the current setup?

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow pass the id into the onclick function.  One way to do that is to set the id of the clicking element like this:

```
each val in post['listitem']
    div.listitem
       .rating_button
         .buttons
           button(id= val.id class='up' aria-pressed="false") Upvote
           p#vote 0 //currently 0 later data from db
           button(id= val.id class='down' ariapressed="false")Downvote
```

Then you capture that by adding a reference to the element in the click function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.up', function(element){

    var id = element.target.id;

    var up = $.post("/api/" + id + "/upvote", {changeBy: 1}, function(dataBack){
        $("#vote").text(dataBack);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! But implementing the code buttons are still not working as I want. When I click one button in the loop it is increasing/decreasing every number in the loop

Comment: I think you might have left some code out then.  I can't see where you are setting the values locally.  It will be something similar to this, you need to isolate your list values by the id of the button clicked.